# What is the angle of inclination joining (1,4) and (3,7)

Tags: calculus

I have found the slope of this line to be 3/2

I used the equation $\dfrac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1} =  (7-4)/(3-1)=3/2$

I then found the equation of the line to be $y=3/2x+ 2.5$
 I used the equation $y=mx+b$:

$4=3/2(1)+b \implies 2.5=b$

I do not know how to find the angle of inclination

Comment: slope = $tan\theta$

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to find the equation of the line, unless otherwise instructed to do so.

All we need is to know is the following: $$\tan \theta = \dfrac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}} = \dfrac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1} = \text{slope} = \frac 32$$

Now, what value of $\theta$ gives us $\tan \theta = \dfrac 32\;?$

We can use the following: $$\theta = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac 32\right),\quad 0\lt \theta \lt \pi/2$$

Here the reference line for the angle is the line parallel to the $x$-axis, intersecting $(1, 4)$, i.e., the line $y = 1$, and since slope is positive, with the difference between the $x$ and $y$ coordinates both positive, we have that the desired angle will lie in the interval noted above.